# ListView growing to big

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I try to lay out some widgets including one `ListView`. I want the `ListView` fills the available space. If the `ListView` content is to bigger it should be scrollable.
At the moment the `ListView` gets too big and the widgets growing out of the screen.

```
...
body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text('Text'),
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => actionWidgetList[index],
                itemCount: actionList.length,
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
        rangeInitialized
            ? Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: another.widget,
              )
            : SizedBox(),
      ]),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's small widget, part of the bigger layout you probably you know the max height of the ListView

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Text'),
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: 100
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                      actionWidgetList[index],
                  itemCount: actionList.length,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      rangeInitialized
        ? Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: another.widget,
          )
        : SizedBox(),
    ],
  );
}
```

If the layout need to fill the whole screen you can use flexible widgets

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Text'),
                Flexible(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    // shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        actionWidgetList[index],
                    itemCount: actionList.length,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      rangeInitialized
        ? Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: another.widget,
          )
        : SizedBox(),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: No, not what I want. Maybe I didn't explain it good enough. I want that the container on bottom is always there with a fix height. And the ListView above should use the rest of the available space. If the ListView gets to big, the content in the Listview should be scrollable, not the whole screen.

Comment: Thx! The second one is the solution which works for me.

Comment: @kherel i was very lucky to see this post